# Assigning rows of a static 2D array to another's rows

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, notation

Here's what I have so far:

```
    typedef const float Chord[6];

    static Chord progressionOne[] = {
        {5.0f / 6.0f, 1.0, 1.25, 5.0f / 3.0f, 2.0, 2.5},         // i
        {5.0f / 6.0f, 2.0f / 3.0f, 1.0, 4.0f / 3.0f, 5.0f / 3.0f, 2.0}, // VI
        {0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5},                       // III
        {1.125, 1.5, 1.875, 2.25, 3.0, 3.75}                      // VII
    };

    static Chord progressionTwo[] = {
        progressionOne + 1, //VI
        progressionOne + 3, //VII
        progressionOne + 0, // i
        progressionOne + 0,
    };
```

This seems to be the closest I can get in several rounds of massaging my notation, swapping around asterisks and adjusting the typedef. What I want, which is hopefully clear in context, is to rearrange `progressionTwo`'s rows, yielding `progressionTwo`. I don't mind data duplication or hairy notation--I'd just like to be [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) enough to avoid typing the actual values twice.

...I really need to get around to reading the standard :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want these to be simple arrays, you could simply create `#define` macros (pre-processor definitions) for the chords, and make the progressions reference those chords:

```
typedef const float Chord[6];

#define CHORD_I { 5.0f / 6.0f, 1.0, 1.25, 5.0f / 3.0f, 2.0, 2.5 }
#define CHORD_VI { 5.0f / 6.0f, 2.0f / 3.0f, 1.0, 4.0f / 3.0f, 5.0f / 3.0f, 2.0 }
#define CHORD_III { 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5 }
#define CHORD_VII { 1.125, 1.5, 1.875, 2.25, 3.0, 3.75 }

const Chord progressionOne[] = {
    CHORD_I,
    CHORD_VI,
    CHORD_III,
    CHORD_VII,
};

const Chord progressionTwo[] = {
    CHORD_VI,
    CHORD_VII,
    CHORD_I,
    CHORD_I,
};
```

Pre-processor definitions are are messy, though.

If you turn `Chord` into a full-blown class, you can define them as locals or static variables in the same way, but with more type safety, and more flexibility.  Then you could reference `progressionOne` while defining `progressionTwo` the way that you want (at least you can with locals.  With globals, you might run into a ["static order initialization fiasco"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15))

Comment: +1, got ahead by 15 secs. One comment, you can `#undef` these macros after their usage to be on safer side.

Comment: Not quite what I was expecting, but this actually works quite nicely, evil macros notwithstanding ;) You're probably right about biting the bullet and writing a class, too.